# Given the coordinates of a cursor location, can you access info related to what the cursor would click on?

Tags: winforms, powershell

Currently I have my powershell script to where it can log the x,y coordinates of every click the user makes a left click of a mouse button.

```
while(1){
    if([System.Windows.Forms.UserControl]::MouseButtons -eq "Left"){
    Out-File -FilePath $logfile -Encoding Unicode -Append -InputObject $([DateTime]::UtcNow.ToString('u')) -NoNewline
    Out-File -FilePath $logfile -Encoding Unicode -Append -InputObject " | LeftMouseButton clicked at: " -NoNewline
    Out-File -FilePath $logfile -Encoding Unicode -Append -InputObject $([System.Windows.Forms.Cursor]::Position).ToString()
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100
}
```

I would like to be able to store more information other than just the timestamp and the coordinates. Is there any way I can access information related to what the user is clicking on? For example, if the user clicks on the Chrome shortcut, it could store that information in the log file. I've searched through the System.Windows.Forms namespace and can't really find anything that leads me to believe this is possible, but I would appreciate some advice as to whether or not this is doable.